# Change AutoGenerateSelectButton display

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm new to asp.net. I would like to ask if there is a way to change the text of AutoGenerateSelectButton property, what I want is to display some data from my database instead of "select" text display only. Any help please? thanks in advance

below is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="ID"
            Style="float: right" Width="675px" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"   BorderStyle="Solid"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtFName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        txtFName.Enabled = false;
        txtMName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        txtMName.Enabled = false;
        txtLName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
        txtLName.Enabled = false;
        rbtnGender.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
        rbtnGender.Enabled = false;
        rbtCStatus.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
        rbtCStatus.Enabled = false;
        ddlBirthMonth.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
        ddlBirthMonth.Enabled = false;
        ddlBirthDate.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
        ddlBirthDate.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want control over how the select button renders, create it yourself. You can add a TemplateField field to your columns section

```
<asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
                 CommandName="Select"
                 headertext="Select Item" 
                 text="Your Custom Text"/>
```

What is important here is the [CommandName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx) property. Out of the box grids support commands like Select, Update, Delete, etc.

Comment: Oh my goshh I spent a lot of time to make this work. I got it! Thanks a lot my friend. I did not realized to use this control/technique. I was focused my code shown above. Thanks again!